# Perl 5.6.1 vs. Perl 5.14 - converting dec to hex

Tags: perl, hex, printf

I found something strange.
Different behaviors for different versions of perl.

The code is:

```
$x = -806;
$x = sprintf "0x%x" , $x;
print "$x";
```

In 5.6.1 i get:
0xfffffcda

In 5.14 i get:
0xfffffffffffffcda

How can i get 32-bit in 5.14 as well?

Thanks!

Comment: Note that it's not related to the Perl version. You can have a 64-bit build of Perl 5.6 and a 32-bit build of 5.14.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing with negative numbers is they're represented via 2s complement binary. What you're seeing is the result of the word size being larger.

I'm not entirely sure precisely why it would have changed (aside from 14 years and a general move to 64bit), but it's not easy to fix without recompiling perl. I'd suggest that's not a good idea since what you're really trying to get is a stringification.

A simpler solution would be a bitwise AND with the appropriate length bitmask:

```
$x = -806;
$x = sprintf ("0x%x" , $x & 0xffffffff);
print "$x";
```

Comment: Simple and genius! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Some addition to the answer above:

The number of digits Perl produces when its `sprintf` converts to hex depends on the size of the native C data type Perl uses internally to store unsigned integer values. What type that is is determined by Perl's `Configure` script when it sets things up to compile the Perl interpreter, so it's not exactly something that can be changed at run time. It can also vary from operating system to operating system and machine to machine, so if you run your script in different environments you can't be sure how many hex digits will be produced (a point strongly in favor of Sobrique's suggestion). It's also quite likely that the default native type was changed from a 32-bit one to a 64-bit one at some point during the 14 years since 5.6.1 was released.

If you want to know what type is used in a particular perl installation, `perl -MConfig -E 'say $Config{uvtype}'` will tell you (modify as needed for pre-5.10 perls).